# kill -9 but using name instead of number

Tags: bash, shell, signals, kill, sigkill

I am using kill like so:

```
pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -9
```

but I am wondering what the name version of kill -9 is, I thought it was:

```
pgrep -P $$ | xargs kill -KILL
```

but that doesn't seem to work, b/c the child procs appear to live on.

Comment: Try `man killall`.

Comment: yeah I am looking for -SIGNAL that corresponds to -9, but the name, maybe it is `-SIGKILL` not `-KILL`

Comment: `-9`, `-SIGKILL` and  `-KILL` are all good.

Comment: Since `kill` is a shell built-in, from `man bash`:  *sigspec is either  a  case-insensitive
              signal  name such as SIGKILL (with or without the SIG prefix) or
              a signal number*

Answer (score 1):

On linux, it is `KILL`. You can get the list of signal names using `kill -l`

```
kill -l | head -n2
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGBUS       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGUSR1
```

When you kill the parent, the child becomes orphaned and it is inherited by `init`

```
+~ ->ps -p 5783,5784,2212 -o pid,ppid,command                                                        
  PID  PPID COMMAND
 2212  1914 -bash
 5783  2212 /bin/bash ./parent.sh  
 5784  5783 /bin/bash ./child.sh 

+~ ->kill -KILL 5783

+~ ->ps -p 5783,5784,2212 -o pid,ppid,command
  PID  PPID COMMAND
 2212  1914 -bash
 5784     1 /bin/bash ./child.sh

+~ ->ps -fp 1 -o pid,command
  PID COMMAND
    1 /sbin/init splash
```

See the example above.